# YouTube embed iframe not showing in Safari

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, safari

The link is http://thecodeclub.org/ and there is a YouTube video.

Works fine in Chrome but the iframe remains blank in Safari?

Has anyone else encountered this or have a fix?

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-style2">
<article id="work">
  <header>
    <h2>What Most Schools Don't Teach</h2>
    <p>Even rap stars are learning to code...</p>
  </header>
 <div class="video-container">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nKIu9yen5nc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
<a href="#courses" class="button button-big">The Courses.</a>

</article>
 </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if you fixed it but I can see the video fine in Safari on Mavericks.  Perhaps some extension issue in Safari could be blocking it?

Comment: Hi Nick. Solved it in the end was just down a CSS malfunction. Thanks for the note though.

Comment: @PatGW can you please post your resolved css issue here?

Comment: Hi @TamasKalman I have added the details below. Just changed https to http and that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In the end it was the https that was causing the issue. Changed it to http as below and it worked fine.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KX5PdVd1-OU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```