# youtube Iframe video not working on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

When i Click on the full screen option in Safari, the video gets enlarged in half of the screen than full.

I have used basic iframe from youtube video. I used it in a custom website. What can be the issue here ? Kindly Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This explains it https://tubularinsights.com/youtube-adds-iframe-embed-code-no-iphone/

and [Making youtube.com/embed URLs work on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969334/making-youtube-com-embed-urls-work-on-ios)

also its is a duplicate to these two :
 [youtube embed video not working with safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494102/youtube-embed-video-not-working-with-safari)

[YouTube embed iframe not showing in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890682/youtube-embed-iframe-not-showing-in-safari)