# Embedding YouTube video with playlist argument sometimes shows "This video is unavailable"

Tags: video, youtube, playlist

I have a website where I embed YouTube videos with this link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHOX6jH00kE?autoplay=1&loop=1&list=UHOX6jH00kE
```

and the syntax from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041088/getting-an-embedded-youtube-video-to-auto-play-and-loop):

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHOX6jH00kE?autoplay=1&loop=1&list=UHOX6jH00kE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen)
```

Sometimes, this embedding works and I see the video, e.g. [this page](https://ginja.org/en/cancao/1). Other times, e.g. [this page](https://ginja.org/pt/cancao/10) the embed doesn't work and I see "This video is unavailable":

[image: YouTube video unavailable]

If I refresh the page with `Cmd-R`, then the video shows. If I remove the `playlist` GET argument, e.g. with embed link `https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHOX6jH00kE?autoplay=1&loop=1`, then it also shows.

Sometimes, if I check on my alternative domain (that redirects to the same server; the only difference is the default language), then I see the video, the video sometimes shows, e.g.: https://brokkolat.org/pt/cancao/10 .

How can I embed a YouTube video that loops and always shows without refreshing?

Answer (score 2):

Try change your URL as follows:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHOX6jH00kE?autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&enablejsapi=1
```

I've tested on jsfiddle and on my browser (*Google Chrome*) and it works.

Keep in mind that for autoplay on Google Chrome, it seems it's need to the video starts muted.

Code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UHOX6jH00kE?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&enablejsapi=1">
</iframe>
```

Example with another video - [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356392/4092887) for a detailed explanation:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QwS1r1mc888?enablejsapi=1&loop=1&playlist=QwS1r1mc888&autoplay=1&mute=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white">    
</iframe>
```

Comment: This code works on Google Chrome and loops the video. It doesn't on Safari, any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @miguelmorin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31561351/4092887) says the issue is due the `https` on the video URL. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34760448/4092887) points to add additional tags. I don't have Safari, but, please try and let us know.

Comment: Changing from `https` to `http` does not show the iframe, it's just blank. Changing `iframe` to `object` and `shockwave-flash` and a link like `http://www.youtube.com/v/[VIDEO_ID]` works and shows the video; adding `?autoplay=1&loop=1` shows the video and fails to loop; adding `?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=[VIDEO_ID]` shows the same screen the first time, "This video is unavailable`, as before.

Comment: @miguelmorin then try to [post a ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&;template=874803&hl=es&template=874803) on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191640&s=created_time:desc) - though, that forum is for YouTube Data API, maybe you will find some clues about how to proceed.

Comment: Done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/284737598 . Thank you Mauricio.

Comment: I got this answer on the issue tracker: "Hi, this is a known issue. I'll report the details of your concern with our internal team. Will update this thread for any updates. Thanks."

Comment: @miguelmorin well done. Click the `+1`  on the ticket as well. Let's hope they provide an official answer. Thanks.